Does "residualising" out the effect of a covariate on the response variable achieve similar results to including the covariate as a predictor?
Sorry - the question itself is wordy!
I am running a Welch ANOVA, but want to account for the effects of a covariate on this Welch ANOVA. I am unaware of any ways that I could conduct a Welch ANCOVA.
What I have tried is running linear regression with the continuous covariate (age) as the predictor, which is what I am interested in accounting for in the Welch ANOVA. I save the residuals from this regression and then run Welch ANOVAs, with the grouping variable and the saved residuals being the response variable (which, from my very possibly incorrect understanding, removes the effect of age in the relationship between the grouping variable and response variable?).
Is this approach reasonable?
Related Q: What might the differences be between this, and running a standard ANCOVA (apart from the usage of Welch's test)?
Thanks a lot! :)

Why use Welch ANOVA? I'm guessing that when you ran the multiple regression, there were issues (but I may be wrong). But you could run robust regression.

Hi Peter,
I am using Welch ANOVA because I am comparing the response variable across 5 levels of an ordinal variable, and the homogeneity of variance assumption was violated.
I have been running Welch ANOVAs with no covariates, but in the literature (and I can almost guarantee I will get a question on this during my presentation), age is strongly related to the response variable. So, I'm predicting the question "why haven't I controlled for age", whilst trying to keep analyses as similar as they were before...

You can use a categorical response in robust regression. Ordinal independent variables are a bit tricky, some people just treat them as categorical, others as numeric.  One method for them that I think has promise but that I haven't seen used much is optimal scaling.  And, AFAIK, Welch ANOVA doesn't solve this problem.

Thanks Peter :) I'll look into robust regression more!
